# Cloudera Manager installer 3.7 trying to install Cloudera manager server 4.5

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am trying to install CDH3U5 on our cluster which has RHEL 5.5, using Cloudera Manager 3.7.x. However the installation fails because of the following error -

```
Error Downloading Packages:
  cloudera-manager-daemons-4.5.1-1.cm451.p0.294.x86_64: failure: RPMS/x86_64/cloudera-manager-daemons-4.5.1-1.cm451.p0.294.x86_64.rpm from cloudera-manager: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

A view of the logs show that -

```
================================================================================
 Package                    Arch   Version               Repository        Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 cloudera-manager-server    x86_64 4.5.1-1.cm451.p0.294  cloudera-manager 7.5 k
Updating for dependencies:
 cloudera-manager-daemons   x86_64 4.5.1-1.cm451.p0.294  cloudera-manager 132 M
 cloudera-manager-server-db x86_64 4.5.1-1.cm451.p0.294  cloudera-manager 9.0 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       0 Package(s)
Upgrade       3 Package(s)

Total size: 132 M
Total download size: 132 M
Downloading Packages:
http://archive.cloudera.com/cloudera-manager/redhat/5/x86_64/cloudera-manager/3/RPMS/x86_64/cloudera-manager-daemons-4.5.1-1.cm451.p0.294.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
```

Clearly the path is invalid. I have tried to get the file using browser as well. So I have following queries

- Why is a 3.7 installer trying to install a 4.5 setup?
- Any idea how I can get the URLs it is looking at fixed so the RPMs are downloaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the yum.

Try to do clean yum

```
$ yum --enablerepo='*'clean all
$ rm -rf /var/cache/yum/cloudera*
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Some of the items may be cached in a deeper location (i.e. /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/cloudera*)

To make sure you completely clean the cache, try the following and delete anything cloudera-manager related.

    $ find /var/cache/yum | grep cloudera-manager